# Let $G,K$ be groups with $H\le G$. It is not always possible to extend a homomorphism $\sigma:H\to K$ to $G$

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, group-homomorphism

This is **Exercise 4.2** of Roman's, *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach"*. According to [this MSE search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgroup-theory%5D+not+always+possible+to+extend+homomorphism+) and [this Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24H%5Cle%20G%24%2C%20extend%20homomorphism%2C%20%24%5Csigma%3A%20H%5Cto%20K%24&p=1), it is new to MSE.

### The Question:

> Let $G$ and $K$ be groups with $H\le G$. Show that it is not always possible to extend a homomorphism $\sigma:H\to K$ to $G$.

### Thoughts:

This looks, *prima facie*, like a job for the extreme cases, like $K$ (and hence $H$) being trivial, although I haven't found anything; the solution seems more elusive than that.

My second idea came in the form of supposing $G$ and $K$ are finite, then employing some trick - I don't know what yet - with the orders of the groups involved, like Lagrange's Theorem for the subgroup $H$ in $K$, aiming to get $\lvert \sigma'(G)\rvert\nmid \lvert K\rvert$ somehow, for some potential extension $\sigma':G\to K$. This seems feasible at first but, after a while, I have doubts.

---

Besides, I'm not entirely sure whether the extension is from $H$ to $G$ or from $K$ to $G$ (if you see what I mean). The word "extension" is defined only once prior to the exercise *ibid.* but it is in an entirely different context. For completeness, here is that definition:

> Let $G$ be a group. We refer to subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$ for which $H\le K$ as an *extension*.

Please help :)

Comment: The extension is to a homomorphism $\sigma':G\to K$ whose restriction to $H$ is $\sigma$.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you, @BrianM.Scott.

Comment: Are you familiar with $S_3$ (also called $D_3$)?

Comment: Come on, now, @BrianM.Scott; surely you know me better than that by now! Yes.

Comment: How about division by $2$ $2\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I don't follow, @Thorgott.

Comment: Can that be extended to a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Got it! Thank you, @Thorgott. I invite you to write an answer.

Comment: @Shaun: Sorry: I didn’t actually register who submitted the question!

Comment: No worries, @BrianM.Scott. So, what about $S_3$?

Comment: @Shaun: Take it for $G$, and let $H=K=A_3$, $\sigma$ being the identity map. Any extension would have to take the elements of order $2$ to the identity, but then the kernel has $4$ elements. Oops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The division-by-$2$ map $2\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z},\,k\mapsto k/2$ is a bona fide group homomorphism, but it cannot be extended to a group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, for such an extension $\tilde{f}$ would have to satisfy
$$1=f(2)=\tilde{f}(2)=2\tilde{f}(1),$$
yet no such integer $\tilde{f}(1)$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

The other commenter's example was better but here's one using simple groups. Assume $G$ is a non-cyclic simple group and let $n$ be the order of $\sigma \in G$ and take the natural isomorphism $f: \langle \sigma \rangle \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Then if $f$ extended to a homomorphism $F: G \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, it would be an isomorphism since its kernel would have to be trivial by the simplicity of $G$, contradicting the fact that $G$ was not cyclic.